# Highcharts - Number fixed of points

Tags: charts, real-time, highcharts

Just recently started to use the Highcharts. I'm using API Highstock to generate a graph real time, but I have a doubt. How do I have a set number of points in my chart? For example, if I send only two points, I don't want the chart is self adjusting for these two points, but it gets fixed to say, receiving 20 points.

thank you

Comment: I now understand: you want to always have data points plotted at the same dimensions (width of columns, etc.) all the time. I think this is not possible as far as I know. Keeping fixed widths of data points means the width of the whole chart width should adjust for each dataset, depending on the number of points that should be rendered. If the data is dynamic, the only way I see it, then you should process that data to manipulate it to insert null data points before feeding them into the chart.

Comment: An example with fiddle would be more helpful